# laravel storage link not working on another system

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have an existing laravel project that I wrote on a Windows PC, I tried to copy the project to a MacBook and it runs well, but the problem is the storage:link doesn't work, all the picture I save in the storage folder can't be accessed through the app, I tried to enter the link of the files manually on the browser and it's still doesn't work.

I also checked the folder and the files, they still exist.

I'm still new in using Mac, does anyone have a solution?

I also tried to upload my laravel project to a shared hosting without SSH access, how can I make a storage link?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a shared hosting service and move everything in laravel's public directory into hosting's public_html and move everything beside laravel's public directory into a new folder I generate in the same directory as the public_html directory such as below:

- root / parent directory

  - public_html
  - laravel

Make a file in public folder named symlink.php which contains this code:

```
<?php
    $targetFolder = '../laravel/storage/app/public';
    $linkFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/storage';
    if(symlink($targetFolder,$linkFolder)){
        echo 'Symlink completed';
    } else {
        echo 'Symlink Failed';
    }
?>
```

you can specify the $targetFolder variable to your storage/app/public path like above.

afterwards call the file through your laravel link.
eg:
http://mylaravel-example.com/symlink.php

nb : the file's name is not a fixity, you can specify it as you desired.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, maybe this is for wrong file locations. well, if you can find the folders you want to link you can run a raw command anyway

```
ln -s /project_folder/storage/app/public /project_folder/public/storage
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you move the project to another system or directory , you need to recreate the symlink. Re run the command

> php artisan storage:link

Comment: I did that already but still nothing changes.

Comment: delete previously create symlink and rerun the command. hope it works

Comment: just tried that, a minute ago, and it finally works. Thank you.